# Is it necessary to mention http/https in the URL, when accessing another port?

Tags: rest, web-services, http, url, request

I was trying to access a REST endpoint (`http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users`) when all of a sudden, the below realization hit me.

http is assigned port 80, and I was trying to access port 8080 of the server, hence why use http in the URL?

Is it because we want to specify the protocol being used (http/https), or for any other reasons?

Comment: ...because, lacking the scheme name, it is not an absolute URI (URL).

Comment: uhmm,  is it only due to scheme name compulsion? ( also, can't a valid URL start with authority? )

Comment: HTTP pertains not just to the default port, but also which protocol to speak.

Comment: @Evert so, only for the protocol, and no other reason right?

Comment: It's also to discern whether the url is absolute or not, as Julian mentioned. If you're curious about the entire structure and purpose of each part of a uri, go to the source: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986

Comment: There's plenty of URIs that are not http or https. Here's a list: https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xhtml

Comment: Thank you JulianReschke and Evert, I now understand this better.